# Converting group of IPs to CIDR notation

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out a way to convert a range of IPs such as 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2, all the way to 1.255 to something like 192.168.0.1/23. Any ideas? I'm taking in an input file containing Ips and just want to summarize them up as much as possible.

Comment: Ruby has built in support using [NetAddr::CIDR](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/n/netaddr-1.5.0/NetAddr/CIDR.html), which you could have found with a simple search for "[ruby ip cidr](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ruby+ip+cidr&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)". Or you can look at the [IPAddress](https://github.com/bluemonk/ipaddress) gem, which also supports CIDR and also has the necessary methods to convert.

Comment: Yes -- I know I could have done a simple search and I did. However, I'm not understanding how to get to the end result.

Comment: Also, the IPAddress gem's example only takes one IP address...

Comment: Please include the code of your attempts at using the method suggested. A [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be useful for others to help you.